# For-loop is never entered

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, for-loop

I have a function meant to construct an array full of objects using a for-loop. However, my debugger jumps over the for-loop for some reason, and i don't know why. here is the function:

```
function objArrCon() { //object array constructor 
    var arr = [];
    var len = 9;
    for (var i = 2; i === len; i++) {
        arr.push({
            name: i,
            count: 0
        });
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Because `2 !== 9`; did you mean to write `i < len`?

Comment: Try changing it to `i < len`

Comment: The `len` is probably not needed ,so you can do straight `i < 9`

Comment: Or perhaps you mean `arr.length != len`? What's the expected outcome?

Comment: len is a placeholder for a function call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
for (var i = 2; i === len; i++) {
```

Should be

```
for (var i = 2; i <= len; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

change you for loop like this. this my helps you

```
function objArrCon() { //object array constructor 
    var arr = [];
    var len = 9;
    for (var i = 2; i <= len; i++) { // change this line
        arr.push({
            name: i,
            count: 0
        });
    }
    return arr;
}
```